# BSOD error 0x0000006B PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED on boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, system-restore

I reinstalled League of Legends because the patcher always gave me an error. However, out of complete stupidness I didn't uninstall the old installation first because I thought that it would simply replace the files. However, when the installer bar got to 100% it simply minimized. Then I closed the application from the task manager. I tried uninstalling it after a failed attempt to start it up. The same behavior as when I installed it. Then I tried reinstalling where it simply presented the InstallShield Modify/Repair/Remove menu and I selected repair. Nothing happened.

Then I tried selecting Modify, then seeing that the only option (called DefaultFeature) was unchecked. Same behaviour as install/uninstall. After seeing that it still failed, I uninstalled again. And after that I deleted C:\Program Files (x86)\League of Legends manually. When I tried installing LoL again it still thought I had it, so I chose repair. This time something actually happened, but it installed the whole game to C:\Windows. Seeing what was going on I clicked cancel and then started it up to try uninstalling it. However, I got an error message about something not being registered and then the minimization to I decided to let it repair completely. Then I uninstalled it and it gave only the minimization.

However, when I rebooted another application started up complaining about some library being absent. So I decided to do a system restore. After letting it complete I got a BSOD (0x0000006B(0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)) every time I tried starting up Windows normally or in safe mode. However, system recovery mode works, although the system recovery automatic repair does not fix it. After a bit of searching I found a Microsoft KB article about it ([981833](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981833/)) and tried following the workaround instructions. Nothing happened.

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit HP OEM and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit installed with WUBI.

Comment: Did you try another restore, pick another restore point?

Comment: @Moab Yes, but all the restore points disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to just go with the reformat option.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't boot, it sounds like you need a system repair.

1. Get any Windows 7 disk.
2. Reboot while tapping F2.
3. Go into BIOS settings, and set your CD/DVD as first boot-able device.
4. Insert the Windows 7 disk into the drive.
5. Reboot.
6. Follow these [instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-from-a-Windows-7-installation-disc-or-USB-flash-drive). **"Recover Windows 7 from a serious error".** Do not choose Install!
7. Choose *REPAIR*.  This will not alter the program entries in the registry.  You won't have to reinstall all your programs.  It simply re-writes any original Windows system files.
8. You will be asked for user name and password, to access the drive.
9. Once *REPAIR* is done, reboot and do a check disk with /fix.  This will repair any file, directory, or index problems.
10. After this, delete the game's directory.
11. Reboot.
12. Then, download a Windows 7 registry cleaner, and clean it thoroughly.  It will remove references to the uninstalled game.
13. Reboot.
14. Reinstall the game.

I wish you well.

Comment: Sadly, I can't do this, since I only have the on-hdd hp restore, which only lets me do a complete restore

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. After 5 and a half hours trying everything, the only end solution was to wipe and reformat the drive and upgrade windows

Comment: This does not add any real significant information.  Resorting to a format isn't really a solution to the author's problem, its a solution and might be the only solution, but this answer itself at best a **comment**.